# Can't click on an object more than once on Mobile. The code works fine on the laptop

Tags: aframe

I want to animate an object on click but the click only registers once on mobile for some reason. Works fine on laptop.

I have tried using mousedown and changing A-Frame version but it doesn't seem to do the job. Using 0.8.2.

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
        init: function() {
          let anim = document.querySelector("#Kanye")
          let anim2 = document.querySelector("#ball")


          this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            //console.log(e)
            //this.el.emit("bar")
            anim2.setAttribute('visible','true')
            anim2.emit("bar")
          })

        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. You are in an old version. Use A-Frame 0.9.2